# Clear XML file before writing data back in

Tags: c#, xml, filestream

Is there a way to clear an XML document out before I write back into it with the Variable.Save(Stream) command?

```
FileStream savingFs = new FileStream("AutoUpdaterCheckList.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
savingFs.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);

xmlDoc.Save(savingFs);
```

Currently, when I write the stream back into the file I get a few leftover characters from the old file that cause the XML to break.

Comment: Why are you using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`? I suspect that's the problem. I'd suggest using `File.Create(...)` instead of calling the `FileStream` constructor at all, to be honest. (And you don't need to see to the start of a file after opening a stream.)

Comment: Clearing a file is basically deleting and creating it new, so use `File.Delete`?

Comment: @RandRandom: You don't need to actively delete it first. Just using `FileMode.Create` or calling `File.Create` will clear any old content out.

Comment: @JonSkeet god damn it it was that easy!!! thank you so much for the assist :) worked like a charm :)

Comment: How are you removing data from the stream?